# Text file download from dropbox

Tags: android, dropbox

I am trying to download a text file from dropbox Photos folder. is this the right way of doing it? as i am getting some warning due to which i guess its not downloading a file

```
public void onClick(View v) {

                File mFile=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "Download1");
                try {
                    FileOutputStream mFileOutputStream=new FileOutputStream(mFile);
                    DropboxFileInfo mDropboxFileInfo=mApi.getFile("/Photos/"+"fileGhh", null, mFileOutputStream, null);
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (DropboxException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    }
            }
```

Here is the Logcat

```
11-22 15:40:51.369: W/System.err(24394): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/sdcardDownload1: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)
11-22 15:40:51.369: W/System.err(24394):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:419)
11-22 15:40:51.369: W/System.err(24394):    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:88)
11-22 15:40:51.369: W/System.err(24394):    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:73)
11-22 15:40:51.369: W/System.err(24394):    at com.example.screenwritter.Dropboxdowload$2.onClick(Dropboxdowload.java:135)
11-22 15:40:51.369: W/System.err(24394):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3574)
11-22 15:40:51.369: W/System.err(24394):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14293)
11-22 15:40:51.369: W/System.err(24394):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
11-22 15:40:51.369: W/System.err(24394):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-22 15:40:51.369: W/System.err(24394):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-22 15:40:51.369: W/System.err(24394):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4448)
11-22 15:40:51.369: W/System.err(24394):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-22 15:40:51.369: W/System.err(24394):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-22 15:40:51.369: W/System.err(24394):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:823)
11-22 15:40:51.369: W/System.err(24394):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:590)
11-22 15:40:51.369: W/System.err(24394):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-22 15:40:51.369: W/System.err(24394): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)
11-22 15:40:51.379: W/System.err(24394):    at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
11-22 15:40:51.379: W/System.err(24394):    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
11-22 15:40:51.379: W/System.err(24394):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:403)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not 100% sure, but I'm guessing you want `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/Download1"`. (Note the leading slash before `Download1`.)

This is based on the error, which seems to be trying to write to `/mnt/sdcardDownload1`. `/mnt/sdcard/Download1` seems like a better path to me.